# convert-im6.q16 (ImageMagick): How to specify command or options?

Tags: bash, imagemagick, photo

In a shell-script (bash) I want to process a bunch of photos.
A first step is to determine the orientation (portrait or landscape) and to turn the picture to its natural orientation.
Depending on the result the script rezises the picture.

Question:
How to use commands?
The man page says:

> -orient type         image orientation
> I have tried `Orient=$(identify-im6.q16 -orient 'type' "$1")`
> resulting in the error message

> identify-im6.q16: unrecognized option `-orient' @ error/identify.c/IdentifyImageCommand/914.
> 1920_1080: the value is too big for the current base (the symbol causing the error is "1920_1080

(this is a translation of the german text "1920_1080: Der Wert ist für die aktuelle Basis zu groß. (Fehlerverursachendes Zeichen ist »1920_1080«)."

I have found somewhere `-format '%w_%h'` which works.

Comment: How do you know the *"natural orientation"*? Have you tried `-auto-orient`?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. `-auto-orient` works fine. That's the main thing.
However I still would like to know the general format of input-options with arguments.

Comment: Try `identify -list orientation` for a list of possible values.